# what is << on string and integer object in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

what is the use of << in ruby on integer and string object.
I tried the following in irb

```
irb(main):001:0> a=1
=> 1
irb(main):002:0> b=3
=> 3
irb(main):003:0> a<<b
=> 8
irb(main):004:0> a+b
=> 4
irb(main):005:0> a="aa"
=> "aa"
irb(main):006:0> b="bb"
=> "bb"
irb(main):007:0> a<<b
=> "aabb"
irb(main):008:0> a+b
=> "aabbbb"
```

Comment: Did you bother to read the documentation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On integers, it is the [bit-shift-left operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-3C-3C): `a << b` is (barring overflows) equivalent to `a * (2 ** b)`.

On [strings](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) and [arrays](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C), it is append (concatenate-to-this) operator.